# Why refused notifications permission can't be reactivated

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

The first time the user starts our app, we ask him to allow the notification permission.

If he did accept it, in iOS, we can go to the Settings->our app and see the Notifications that can be disabled or reanabled.

Though, if the user refuses the permission at the start up of the app, it can't be activated anymore in the Settings of the app because... it does not show up!

Is it a normal behavior?

Beside deleting the app or "Reset Location & Privacy" (from Settings->General->Reset), does it mean I need to check every time the user starts the app and ask again? It does not make sense and will be very annoying.

Any suggestions to try?

Thanks